# Can Bash Emacs shortcuts be enabled over SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, keyboard-shortcuts

I find Bash keyboard shortcuts such as `Ctrl-a` (jump to start of line), `Ctrl-k` (cut text following caret), `Ctrl-n`/`Ctrl-p` (next/previous line in command history) immeasurably useful in day-to-day CLI work.

It's a shame that these shortcuts don't work when SSH'd into a remote `xterm`.

Is there a way to enable these shortcuts over SSH?

Comment: These commands should work over SSH. What happens if you `set -o emacs`?

Comment: And `ps $$`?  It might not even be `bash`.  (`ksh` and `zsh` default to `vi` bindings if `EDITOR=vi`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing command line (including shortcuts) is a feature of a shell, not a terminal emulator (for the most part). So just put bash into emacs mode on a remote `xterm`:

```bsh
$ set -o emacs
```

Comment: This works like a charm, sincere thanks.